# Lazy val to implement lazy lists in Scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to learn how to use the built-in laziness in Scala by implementing my own version of lazy lists:

```
object LazyList {

  def empty[A] : LazyList[A] = new LazyList[A] {
    lazy val uncons = None
  }

  def cons[A](h : => A, t : => LazyList[A]) : LazyList[A] = new LazyList[A] {
    lazy val uncons = Some( (h,t) )
  }

  def from(s : Int) : LazyList[Int] = new LazyList[Int] {
    lazy val uncons = Some( (s,from(s + 1)) )
  }
}

trait LazyList[A] {

  import LazyList._

  def uncons : Option[(A,LazyList[A])]

  def fmap[B](f : A => B) : LazyList[B] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => cons(f(h),t.fmap(f))
  }

  def take(i : Int) : LazyList[A] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => if (i <= 0) empty else cons(h,t.take(i - 1))
  }

  override def toString : String = uncons match {
    case None          => "[]"
    case Some( (h,t) ) => "[" ++ h.toString ++ ",..]"
  }
}
```

This seems to work and I can, for instance, map `{ _ + 2}` to the infinite list:

```
> LazyList from 1 fmap { _ + 2 }
res1: LazyList[Int] = [2,..]
```

I decided to implement some functions that I usually use like `drop`, `take`, etc and I've been able to implement them except for `inits`. My implementation of `inits` is:

```
  def inits : LazyList[LazyList[A]] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => cons(empty,t.inits.fmap(cons(h,_)))
  }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work on infinite lists for some reason. I can't, for example, write:

```
  > LazyList from 1 inits
```

because it runs forever. The problem seems to be `fmap` after `t.inits` that, for some reason, breaks the laziness (if I remove `fmap` it is wrong but lazy). Why `fmap` enforce strictness and, given my type `LazyList`, how can `inits` be implemented such that it works on infinite lists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `fmap` and `inits` peel one actual (non-lazy) element when invoked; they both `uncons`.  Since they call each other, the chain never terminates on an infinite `LazyList`.

Specifically, note that `uncons` returns not a `=> LazyList` but the actual `LazyList`, so when you call

```
Some( (h,t) )
```

that *evaluates* `t`.  If the evaluation of `t` calls an `uncons`, it too will evaluate and you're off to the stack overflow races.  It's just tricky to notice here because it's dual recursion.

You need to make one of them peel *zero* copies.  One way you can do that is by making the second argument of the `uncons` tuple lazy (explicitly, by making it a `Function0` instead):

```
object LazyList {
  def empty[A]: LazyList[A] = new LazyList[A] {
    lazy val uncons = None
  }

  def cons[A](h: => A, t: => LazyList[A]) : LazyList[A] = new LazyList[A] {
    lazy val uncons = Some( (h,() => t) )
  }

  def from(s: Int): LazyList[Int] = new LazyList[Int] {
    lazy val uncons = Some( (s,() => from(s + 1)) )
  }
}

trait LazyList[A] {
  import LazyList._

  def uncons: Option[(A,() => LazyList[A])]

  def fmap[B](f: A => B): LazyList[B] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => cons(f(h),t().fmap(f))
  }

  def take(i: Int): LazyList[A] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => if (i <= 0) empty else cons(h,t().take(i - 1))
  }

  override def toString: String = uncons match {
    case None          => "[]"
    case Some( (h,t) ) => "[" ++ h.toString ++ ",..]"
  }
}
```

Then your implementation works:

```
  def inits: LazyList[LazyList[A]] = uncons match {
    case None          => empty
    case Some( (h,t) ) => cons(empty,t().inits.fmap(cons(h,_)))
  }
```

It might be nicer to have an internal uncons that did this and an outward-facing uncons that applies the tail for you.

Comment: Still strange to me: cons takes `t: => LazyList[A]` so it is lazy and uncons is a `lazy val`, so why `cons` evaluates the tail?  If I write `cons(f(h),t.fmap(f))`, for example, both `f(h)` and `f.fmap(f)` should be lazy and not evaluated until needed. Why they are needed?

Comment: @mariop - `Some( (h,t) )` is not lazy.  You evaluate the `t` there.  I've edited my answer above to try to highlight this a little more.